# Script to merge layers that are copies Photoshop

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

I am new to scripting on photoshop and it seems not all javascript is the same. What I'm trying to do is I have a list of layers that are as follows:

Cat pic 1.jpg

Cat pic 1.jpg copy

Dog pic 1.jpg

Dog pic 1.jpg copy

....

I want to merge the ones that are copies of each other so "Cat pic 1.jpg" and "Cat pic 1.jpg copy" and create one layer from the two which is just "Cat pic 1.jpg".

They are all active and there is no shapes or anything so its just layers. I have about 300 layers and each one is exactly like that. There is a duplicate of each layer and the name has copy at the end. I wrote a script but I don't know how to merge two layers together. My code doesn't work. It is pieced together from someone trying to sort the layers alphabetically.

Basically I had a layer list and I flipped it horizontally and now I need to merge the left half with the right half. The left is without the word 'copy'.

Any help is greatly appreciated guys! Please feel free to ignore all my code I have zero confidence in it.

Thanks in advance!

```js
#target photoshop
    var layers = activeDocument.layers;
 var layersArray = [];
 var len = layers.length;
 
 // store all layers in an array
 for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  layersArray.push(layers[i]);
 }

var layersOrig= [];
 for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var cond = myIndexOf(layersArray[i], "copy");
    if (cond === -1) {
       layersOrig.push(layersArray[i]); 
       delete layersArray[i];
    }
 }
    layersOrig.sort();
 // sort layer top to bottom
 layersArray.sort();
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    layersArray[i] = merge(layersOrig[i], layersArray[i];
 }
 for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  layersArray[i].move(layers[i], ElementPlacement.PLACEBEFORE);
 }

function myIndexOf(array, x){
 var n=-1, N=array.length;
 while (++n<N && array[n]!==x);
 return n<N ? n : -1;
 };
```

Comment: Are there any groups in the file or is it just a stack of layers? And secondly I noticed that `layersArray[i] = merge(layersOrig[i], layersArray[i];` is missing a right parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
function main()
{
    var layersInfo = getAllLayersNames(); //getting myself an object of layer names and IDs

    for (layerName in layersInfo)
    {
        deselectLayers(); //deselecting all layers first

        if (layersInfo[layerName].length == 1) continue; //if there's only one layer in the object: ignore it

        for (var i = 0; i < layersInfo[layerName].length; i++)
        {
            selectById(layersInfo[layerName][i], true); //selecting layers-clones by IDs
        }

        mergeDown(); //merge down selected layers

        activeDocument.activeLayer.name = layerName; //renaming the resulting layer to original layer name
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // functions

    function getAllLayersNames()
    {
        var lyrs = {};
        try
        {
            activeDocument.backgroundLayer;
            var layers = 0
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            var layers = 1;
        };
        while (true)
        {
            ref = new ActionReference();
            ref.putIndex(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), layers);
            try
            {
                var desc = executeActionGet(ref);
            }
            catch (err)
            {
                break;
            }

            var lyr = {};
            lyr.name = desc.getString(charIDToTypeID("Nm  "));
            var nameWithoutCopy = lyr.name.replace(/\scopy.*/, '');
            lyr.id = desc.getInteger(stringIDToTypeID("layerID"));
            if (lyrs[nameWithoutCopy] == undefined) lyrs[nameWithoutCopy] = [lyr.id]
            else lyrs[nameWithoutCopy].push(lyr.id);
            layers++;
        }
        return lyrs
    };

    function selectById(id, add)
    {
        var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var ref1 = new ActionReference();
        ref1.putIdentifier(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), id);
        desc1.putReference(charIDToTypeID('null'), ref1);
        if (add) desc1.putEnumerated(stringIDToTypeID("selectionModifier"), stringIDToTypeID("selectionModifierType"), stringIDToTypeID("addToSelection"));
        executeAction(charIDToTypeID('slct'), desc1, DialogModes.NO);
    };

    function deselectLayers()
    {
        var desc60 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var ref30 = new ActionReference();
        ref30.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), charIDToTypeID('Ordn'), charIDToTypeID('Trgt'));
        desc60.putReference(charIDToTypeID('null'), ref30);
        executeAction(stringIDToTypeID('selectNoLayers'), desc60, DialogModes.NO);
    };

    function mergeDown()
    {
        var desc11 = new ActionDescriptor();
        executeAction(charIDToTypeID('Mrg2'), desc11, DialogModes.NO);
    };

}
app.activeDocument.suspendHistory("rename all copies", "main()");
```

Input > Result:

[image]